# Jetty project have some errors on start

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty

jetty project have some error,when i start it in eclipse(have jetty plugin).
but i use ant build the project.and copy the building into the jetty-9.2.9/webapps. it can suss start.

no have use maven.
JDK8
the jetty project use websocket.

```
2020-05-14 13:59:10.518:WARN:oeja.ServletContainerInitializersStarter:main: 
javax.servlet.ServletException: Not running on Jetty, JSR-356 support unavailable
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.onStartup(WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.jetty9.Jetty9Adapter.start(Jetty9Adapter.java:68)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.common.AbstractJettyLauncherMain.launch(AbstractJettyLauncherMain.java:84)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.jetty9.Jetty9LauncherMain.main(Jetty9LauncherMain.java:42)
```

log:

```
2020-05-14 13:59:10.352:WARN:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp932172204-28: org.bouncycastle.x509.extension.X509ExtensionUtil scanned from multiple locations: [jar:file:///F://work/build/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk16-140.jar!/org/bouncycastle/x509/extension/X509ExtensionUtil.class, jar:file:///F://src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk16-140.jar!/org/bouncycastle/x509/extension/X509ExtensionUtil.class]
2020-05-14 13:59:10.352:WARN:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp932172204-28: org.bouncycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper scanned from multiple locations: [jar:file:///F://work/build/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk16-140.jar!/org/bouncycastle/x509/util/LDAPStoreHelper.class, jar:file:///F://src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk16-140.jar!/org/bouncycastle/x509/util/LDAPStoreHelper.class]
2020-05-14 13:59:10.352:WARN:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp932172204-28: org.bouncycastle.x509.util.StreamParser scanned from multiple locations: [jar:file:///F://work/build/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk16-140.jar!/org/bouncycastle/x509/util/StreamParser.class, jar:file:///F://src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk16-140.jar!/org/bouncycastle/x509/util/StreamParser.class]
2020-05-14 13:59:10.352:WARN:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp932172204-28: org.bouncycastle.x509.util.StreamParsingException scanned from multiple locations: [jar:file:///F://work/build/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk16-140.jar!/org/bouncycastle/x509/util/StreamParsingException.class, jar:file:///F://src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk16-140.jar!/org/bouncycastle/x509/util/StreamParsingException.class]
2020-05-14 13:59:10.352:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanning elapsed time=5424ms
2020-05-14 13:59:10.518:WARN:oeja.ServletContainerInitializersStarter:main: 
javax.servlet.ServletException: Not running on Jetty, JSR-356 support unavailable
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.onStartup(WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.jetty9.Jetty9Adapter.start(Jetty9Adapter.java:68)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.common.AbstractJettyLauncherMain.launch(AbstractJettyLauncherMain.java:84)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.jetty9.Jetty9LauncherMain.main(Jetty9LauncherMain.java:42)
2020-05-14 13:59:10.518:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4445629{/,file:///F://work/build/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{F:\git_d4\OthelloServer\reversi-websocket-2.9.3\work\build\webapp}
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Not running on Jetty, JSR-356 support unavailable
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.jetty9.Jetty9Adapter.start(Jetty9Adapter.java:68)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.common.AbstractJettyLauncherMain.launch(AbstractJettyLauncherMain.java:84)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.jetty9.Jetty9LauncherMain.main(Jetty9LauncherMain.java:42)
Caused by: 
javax.servlet.ServletException: Not running on Jetty, JSR-356 support unavailable
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.onStartup(WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.jetty9.Jetty9Adapter.start(Jetty9Adapter.java:68)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.common.AbstractJettyLauncherMain.launch(AbstractJettyLauncherMain.java:84)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.jetty9.Jetty9LauncherMain.main(Jetty9LauncherMain.java:42)
2020-05-14 13:59:10.529:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@6ac13091{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2020-05-14 13:59:10.529:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @6304ms
-------------------------------------------------
Jetty startup finished in 6.3 s.
Used memory: 45.1 MB of 617.0 MB (7.1 GB maximum)
Console available: type "help".
-------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

this error is fix. because i do not choose the plugin "Enable Websocket support".

but i have new error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext(Lorg/eclipse/jetty/servlet/ServletContextHandler;)Lorg/eclipse/jetty/websocket/jsr356/server/ServerContainer;" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppClassLoader) of the current class, com/dena/server/listener/WebsocketListener, and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/jsr356/server/deploy/WebSocketServerContainerInitializer, have different Class objects for the type org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/ServletContextHandler used in the signature
at com.dena.server.listener.WebsocketListener.contextInitialized(WebsocketListener.java:51)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:800)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:791)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.jetty9.Jetty9Adapter.start(Jetty9Adapter.java:68)
at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.common.AbstractJettyLauncherMain.launch(AbstractJettyLauncherMain.java:84)
at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.jetty9.Jetty9LauncherMain.main(Jetty9LauncherMain.java:42)
```

Answer (score 0):

and i found.
before i started in jetty home.i need rename the lib/websocket -->lib/websocket-bk
but when is start in the eclipse.i do not need do it.